# Alinhar layouts filhos

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu possuo um projeto android que se trata basicamente de um aplicativo para baixar e assistir vídeos online, eu estava utilizando um código personalizado de um controlador de vídeo para o player que peguei na internet, porém decidi criar o meu próprio para poder melhor customizar e por que pretendo implementar o screen cast no player, a princípio funciona bem, porém não consigo organizar o layout do controlador corretamente, estou tentando criar algo semelhante ao player da netflix (imagem de exemplo abaixo) onde os botões de pausa e avançar e retroceder rapidamente ficão no meio da tela enquanto os controladores na base da tela:

[image: Netflix player]

Meu xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/vp_fast_rewind"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rw_10" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/vp_btn_PlayPause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause_circle_outline" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/vp_fast_forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_ffw_10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vp_initialTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/vp_timeline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vp_finalTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Porém todos os elementos layouts filhos estão ficando no topo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pq vc não tenta fazer com `ConstraintLayout` ? é bem mais simples de fazer views complexas como a sua, além de ser responsivo. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: Já pensei em usar o o ConstraintLayout para o player, na verdade já utilizo em meu aplicativo, porém estruturalmente o player seria algo mais linear.

Answer (score 0):

Ao inserir novos elementos eles sempre entraão no topo à esquerda. Utilize a propriedade android:layout_marginTop e android:layout_marginLeft para arrumar seus itens

Comment: Existe alguma forma de inserir a margem de forma que ele calcule automaticamente a altura para manter sempre no centro?

Comment: Acho que não, mas nunca tentei isso antes.